# Is it okay to post a spoiler-tagged answer to a riddle, in the question?

Tags: discussion

For example, a riddle question has the main riddle in the post, and below the main riddle, in the same post, there's a spoiler-tagged solution.

Is this okay? What about posting the solution after *x* hours/days/etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to answer your own question, you can do so by posting an answer to your own question (Stack Exchange allows this!).

You should definitely *not*, however, edit your *question* to contain the answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: Ninja'd! 11 seconds :-)

Comment: Can I post my answer even after I accept other answers?

Comment: @TheBitByte Of course, feel free!

Answer (score 4):

### No.

If you want to post the answer to your own riddle (say if nobody's managed to solve it after a long period), do so in a [self-answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) instead.